# Получение почты через TidPOP3

Tags: indy, delphi, delphi-7

Добрый день, уважаемые программисты! Может ли мне кто-нибудь ответить по какой причине при использовании TidPOP3 для получения почты приходят не все письма?

Comment: функция CheckMessages, которая должна возвращать число писем в ящике работает не верно: отражает не все письма. Есть соображения на этот счет?

Comment: проведите исследование с помощью [telnet](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196748/ru). будут ли отличия?

Comment: @Yura Ivanov не понимаю что мне это даст

Comment: Кто-нибудь может ответить: полчему писем на почты несколько сотен, а видит их всего несколько единиц???

Comment: что за почтовый сервер?
сколько писем в ящике?
какое количество возвращает код?
какая версия indy?

Comment: @АлександрЪ, этим вы сможете проверить кто врет инди или сервер. или вы что-то не так делаете. учитесь локализовывать проблему.

Comment: Скачайте [отсюда](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/Demos/index.EN.aspx) demo, проверьте на нем.

Comment: Да, еще неплохо было бы указать какая версия indy у вас.

Comment: @АлександрЪ, подозреваю что видит только новые (непрочитанные) письма.

Comment: Большое спасибо за варианты!

Проблема оказалась в следующем:
на сервере писем ровно столько сколько нам возвращает свойство CheckMessages, а мне казалось, что их больше, потому что смотрел через Outlook, в котором в настройках было задано: "удалять письма с сервера старше 15 дней".

Письма с сервера удалялись, а в Outlook оставались.

Плохая привычка - сразу паниковать)

Большое спасибо всем участникам обсуждения! @Yura Ivanov Вы оказались правы. Прошу ответить на данную тему, чтобы я мог ее закрыть)

Comment: Убедитесь, что используете максимально актуальную версию InDy 10